# How to negate a queryset function in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this queryset in django 3.1

```
class AuthenticationQuerySet(InheritanceQuerySet):
    def expired(self):
        return self.filter(
            date_created__lt=timezone.localtime() - self.model.ACTIVE_THRESHOLD
        )

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status__in=["PENDING"]).exclude(
            date_created__lt=timezone.localtime() - self.model.ACTIVE_THRESHOLD
        )
```

Notice that I used the same condition but in the exclude function.
I did it like this, because I could not figure out a more simple solution. But it feels like there should be a way to negate what a queryset function filters?

What I imagine and what feels much more natural is something like

```
class AuthenticationQuerySet(InheritanceQuerySet):
    def expired(self):
        return self.filter(
            date_created__lt=timezone.localtime() - self.model.ACTIVE_THRESHOLD
        )

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status__in=["PENDING"]).exclude(self.expired)
```

Is something like this possible?

or should I just go for something like:

```
class AuthenticationQuerySet(InheritanceQuerySet):
    def expired(self):
        return self.filter(self._expired_condition)
    
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status__in=["PENDING"]).exclude(self._expired_condition)
    
    @property
    def _expired_condition(self):
        return Q(date_created__lt=timezone.localtime() - self.model.ACTIVE_THRESHOLD)
```

? but this seems just really ugly and hacky...

Maybe with some simple condition I should go for the first solution and with some really complex one for the last one?

Thanks for suggestions!

EDIT: I changed the first example to make it more obvious I am not looking for an exclude function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expired queryset in active method:

```
def active(self):
        return self.filter(status__in=["PENDING"])
                   .exclude(pk__in=self.expired().values_list('pk', flat=True))
```

Or you can define a custom Lookup __expired for date_created field and then use it in expired and active methods "date_created__expired". [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-lookups/#writing-an-efficient-abs-lt-lookup).